# python module in django not imported correctly

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi, python-module

While trying to use the [RPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO) python module installed on RaspberryPi, using it in one of my request definition in views.py I get

```
Module not imported correctly!
```

[This is the traceback that I got](https://dpaste.de/cTC8I/). Note that I'm using [this repo](https://github.com/thomasmacpherson/piface) as a starting point.

What would be the right way to install RPi and use it properly in Django ? I need RPi because of my motion sensor, using [this tutorial](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/01/cheap-pir-sensors-and-the-raspberry-pi-part-1/) as a starting point for motion sensor but want to integrate it to a django view (page)

Comment: This message seems to be from GPIO itself (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/raspberry-gpio-python/source/browse/source/py_gpio.c?r=b8da656fb650aa8d13a9c0526dd9046971167c2a)) and not from Django (he's just propagating the exception). Have you tried to run it without Django?

Comment: @Salem: Thanks for the comment, the script runs smoothly without the Django but when including it into my views.py file then I got that error.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - `GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)` seems to have an extra space.

Comment: @karthikr: Thanks for your comment but I've just checked my code and looks fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading the module, uncompress and unpack the downloaded file. Then, run the command "python setup.py install". This documentation on installing modules may be useful http://docs.python.org/2/install/.

As far as using the module with Django, I cannot really help with that. This page may help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the thing is that the Django is already installed and I'm trying to use a python script that has acces to some GPIOs inside on my view definition.